# why SQL cannot delete parent row when references are deleted

Tags: sql, derby

I created a database that contains some tables and they are related to each other. But the problem is that I can deleted tthe record from the child tables, however not from the parent table.

See my SQL Tables structure code

```
User:

CREATE TABLE "User"
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(65) NOT NULL,
    "role" varchar(65) NOT NULL
);

Activity:

CREATE TABLE Activity
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    "time" varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    "date" varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    purgedDocumentName varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    user_ID INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_activity_usr FOREIGN KEY (user_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE."User"(ID)
);

Message:

CREATE TABLE Message
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subject varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    deadline varchar(255) NOT NULL
);


WorkflowMessage:

CREATE TABLE WorkflowMessage
(
    user_ID INTEGER ,
    message_ID INTEGER ,
    CONSTRAINT fk_usr_user FOREIGN KEY (user_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE."User"(ID),

    CONSTRAINT fk_usr_msg FOREIGN KEY (message_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE.Message(ID)
);


Document:

CREATE TABLE Document
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    createdDate varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_ID INTEGER ,

    CONSTRAINT fk_doc_user FOREIGN KEY (user_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE."User"(ID)
);


Version:

CREATE TABLE Version
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    versionNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
    mofiedDate varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    newLocation varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    document_ID INTEGER ,

    CONSTRAINT fk_doc_version FOREIGN KEY (document_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE.Document(ID)
);


Trash

CREATE TABLE RemovedDocument
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE.Document(ID),
    newLocation VARCHAR(255)
);



Historical Document

CREATE TABLE HistoricalDocument
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE.Document(ID),
    newLocation VARCHAR(255),
    retentionDate VARCHAR(12)
);


Group

CREATE TABLE "Group"
(
    "rights" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_ID INTEGER ,
    document_ID INTEGER ,
    CONSTRAINT fk_group_document FOREIGN KEY (document_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE.DOCUMENT(ID),

    CONSTRAINT fk_group_usr FOREIGN KEY (user_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE."User"(ID)
);
```

Comment: Can you specify your Delete statement ?

Comment: It seems Derby supports [cascading deletes](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html), meaning if you redefine your foreign keys e.g. `CONSTRAINT fk_activity_usr FOREIGN KEY (user_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE."User"(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE`, that deletion of a user will result in the deletion of child table rows referencing this user

Comment: I already created the database as you can see. How can I alter it to add your code.

Comment: The answer to that question is already in the comment of @StuartLC: use `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the foreign keys (**where it makes sense!**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you can delete rows from child tables, but not from parent tables, is because of the [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) that you added to the child tables when you added foreign keys in the child tables which reference to primary keys in parent tables.

For example, in order to delete a row from table `User` with key `ID = 1`, you would first need to delete all rows where the foreign key `user_ID = 1` in the following tables :

- Activity
- WorkflowMessage
- Document
- Group

As an alternative to manually deleting child rows, what you can do is redefine the foreign keys with [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html), i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE Activity
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    ... other columns
    user_ID INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_activity_usr FOREIGN KEY (user_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE."User"(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE  -- Cascading delete
);
```

What will happen here is that if the referenced parent `User.ID` row is deleted, all the child rows linked in table `Activity` be deleted. (You'll need to repeat the above for all child tables referencing `User.Id`) Use this option with care!

Another alternative is to allow the foreign key to be null in the child table, and then to specify `ON DELETE SET NULL` in the foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE Activity
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    ... other columns
    user_ID INTEGER NULL, -- Nullable
    CONSTRAINT fk_activity_usr FOREIGN KEY (user_ID)
    REFERENCES EDMSDATABASE."User"(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

As with the cascading delete, if a parent `User.Id` row is deleted, then all referencing child rows in `Activity` will have the `UserId` updated to NULL (but not deleted). Again, be cautious of this approach as this can cause child rows to become orphaned.

Comment: If this solves your question, please mark the question as answered by clicking on the tick.