# Spring Boot set ForeignKey to Null when Parent deleted

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Category Entity which can be set to some CredentialData Entity. They are connected with a OneToMany relationship.

I want to be able to delete Categories even when they are used in CredentialData. When I set the Categories CascadeType to ALL/ REMOVE or orphanRemoval than the CredentialData will also be deleted what I dont want to happen. I just want the Category in CredentialData to be set to null when it got deleted. Is there a way to fix this?

CredentialEntity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CredentialData extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "ownerId", nullable = false)
    private User owner;
```

CategoryEntity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Category extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "ownerId", nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<CredentialData> credentialData;
```

Comment: You can not delete parent table column which associate with child table column. first delete child table column after that delete parent table column

Comment: Ok thank you. Then I have to manually set it to null in the service.

Comment: No this is bad option...

Comment: Can you explain why? Because I want to be able to delete the categories without being forced to delete all CredentialData first. But I also want to keep CredentialData with 'null'-category in case a category gets deleted and was already in use.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609400/why-sql-cannot-delete-parent-row-when-references-are-deleted#:~:text=The%20reason%20why%20you%20can,primary%20keys%20in%20parent%20tables.

Comment: ON DELETE SET NULL -> is what I am searching for. is there no way in doing this in spring boot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944137/have-jpa-hibernate-to-replicate-the-on-delete-set-null-functionality
Is what I was searching for. Thank you for your help @FaeemazazBhanej